# Error Call to a member function getFieldNames() on null in codeigniter 4

Tags: codeigniter-4, database-table

I'm trying to get the columns name from "users" table in my database using detFieldNames function in codeigniter 4 but something went wrong.
Here is the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkLWg.png)

Model class:

```
class UsersModel extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $this->builder = $db->table('users');
    }
function getColumns()
    {
        $names = $this->db->getFieldNames('users');
        foreach ($names as $field) {
            echo $field;
        }
        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to manually set/configure the "Query Builder object". Simply set the `$table` protected property on the model to represent the name of the database table.

**UsersModel.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use CodeIgniter\Model;

class UsersModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "users";

    function getColumns(): array|false
    {
        return $this->db->getFieldNames($this->table);
    }
}
```

**UserController.php**

```php
// ...

$columns = (new \App\Models\UsersModel)->getColumns();

foreach ($columns as $column) {
   echo $column;
}
```

### Addendum

You could alternatively just use the [`db_connect()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html?highlight=db_connect) helper method to get the default *"database connection"*. I.e:

`$names = db_connect()->getFieldNames("users")`